# Seg fault doing new vector<string>

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

The following code gets a seg fault on the last line:

```
   HookAct *act = new HookAct;
    act->hkAct = HookAct::PRINT;
    act->params = new vector<string>;
```

Valgrind tells me:

```
==15551== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==15551== Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==15551== at 0x5927026: std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.10)
==15551== by 0x725424A: test (test.cpp:10)
```

Does anyone have any idea why it is doing this?

FYI, here's the [current, temporary] definition of HookAct:

```
struct HookAct {
    enum {
        PRINT
    } hkAct;
    vector<string> *params;
};
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the block of code you posted. The cause of the error is probably elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Cannot duplicate with the code given.

Comment: Yes, the problem seems to be where you actually assign a value to act->params. Don't you have something like `act->params = "somestring"` around somewhere?

Comment: I agree with casablanca; When STL or standard library functions segfault it's probably caused by a buffer overrun or something in an earlier piece of code.

Answer (score 3):

As [Brian said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434748/seg-fault-doing-new-vectorstring/4434795#4434795), the error message points at `str::string` being initialized with `NULL`, which is forbidden. However, your code looks like written by someone who comes from Java or C# and is used to mindlessly `new` everything. In C++, however, automatic storage is preferred.

If you change your code to this

```
struct HookAct {
    enum {
        PRINT
    } hkAct;
    vector<string> params;
    HookAct() : hAct(HookAct::PRINT), params() {}
};
```

no manual dynamic memory managing is necessary anymore:

```
HookAct hookAct;
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you pasted is fine.

I think your problem is probably adding a `NULL` string to the vector `act->params`.